# Discord.py role.members returning empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am having trouble using the role.members feature in discord.py.

```
role.members
```

just returns an empty list. Here is my code:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("")
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        reasons = []

        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if CheckBot.susCheck(self, message.content, susWords):
            reasons.append("Being sus")
            # DM staff, admins, and headstaff(Still working)
            report = "Caught " + str(message.author) + '" being sus with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
            print("")
            print("####################-END-####################")
            print("")
            print(report)

        if CheckBot.badCheck(self, message.content, badWords):
            reasons.append("Saying bad words")
            # DM staff, admins and headstaff(Still working)
            report = "Caught " + str(message.author) + ' saying bad words with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
            print("")
            print("####################-END-####################")
            print("")
            print(report)


        role1 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
        role2 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
        role3 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
        role4 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
        role5 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)

        print(role3.members)

        if role3 in message.author.roles or role4 in message.author.roles or role5 in message.author.roles:
            if CheckBot.spamCheck(self, message.content, 100000000000000000):
                reasons.append("Spam")
                # DM staff, admins, and headstaff(Still working)
                report = "Caught " + str(message.author) + ' spamming with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
                print("")
                print("####################-END-####################")
                print("")
                print(report)
        else:
            if CheckBot.spamCheck(self, message.content, 115):
                reasons.append("Spam")
                # DM staff, admins, owner, and headstaff(Still working)
                report = "Caught " + str(message.author) + ' spamming with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
                print("")
                print("####################-END-####################")
                print("")
                print(report)

client = MyClient()
```

I am very confused by this. I can't find anything online about it. If you're wondering what this bot is about, it should DM mod type roles when somebody breaks the server rules. A friend of mine asked me to do this, and me being me, accepted it. As I saw many people doing it as a learning project. Anything will help.

Answer (score 2):

Please enter the `Members` Intent in your [applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications). This is to prevent abuse of the API and you must enable it if you want to use it.

Go to Bots and enable the following:

[image]

In your code, you should start with the following. If you were using `client` as a variable instead then replace `bot =` with `client =`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()  # Allow the use of custom intents
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
```

Final code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()  # Allow the use of custom intents
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("")
    print('Logged on as: ', client)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    reasons = []

    # don't respond to ourselves
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if CheckBot.susCheck(message.content, susWords):
        reasons.append("Being sus")
        # DM staff, admins, and headstaff(Still working)
        report = "Caught " + str(
            message.author) + '" being sus with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
        print("")
        print("####################-END-####################")
        print("")
        print(report)

    if CheckBot.badCheck(message.content, badWords):
        reasons.append("Saying bad words")
        # DM staff, admins and headstaff(Still working)
        report = "Caught " + str(
            message.author) + ' saying bad words with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
        print("")
        print("####################-END-####################")
        print("")
        print(report)

    role1 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    role2 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    role3 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    role4 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    role5 = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)

    print(role3.members)

    if role3 in message.author.roles or role4 in message.author.roles or role5 in message.author.roles:
        if CheckBot.spamCheck(message.content, 100000000000000000):
            reasons.append("Spam")
            # DM staff, admins, and headstaff(Still working)
            report = "Caught " + str(
                message.author) + ' spamming with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
            print("")
            print("####################-END-####################")
            print("")
            print(report)
    else:
        if CheckBot.spamCheck(message.content, 115):
            reasons.append("Spam")
            # DM staff, admins, owner, and headstaff(Still working)
            report = "Caught " + str(
                message.author) + ' spamming with the following message: \n"' + message.content + '"'
            print("")
            print("####################-END-####################")
            print("")
            print(report)

client.run("token")
```

Comment: How do I do that? I can only find the privileges and the scopes select.

Comment: Updated my answer @graydog6

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious. But I think there is a problem with that. I have all my stuff in a class called MyClient and takes in "discord.Client". I then make a variable at the end called "client" and assign it to my class. So how would I alter this to work with your code?

Comment: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)` @graydog6 or update your question with the code you use

Comment: My bad, should've done that. I just updated my code.

Comment: @graydog6 Updated my answer, update `"token"` at the bottom with your bot token

Answer (score 0):

I have got help from the answer of FluxedScripts. If you just pass  `intents=intents` in `MyClient()` then it'll work with your current code (you do not need to entirely rewrite the code).

An example:

```
...
intents = discord.Intents.default()  # Allow the use of custom intents
intents.members = True
...
...
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('TOKEN')
```